# Is there a better way of writing this data structure in Dart?

Tags: dictionary, dart, structure

Map in Dart is an hash table, am I right?

```
Map starsData = {
        'stars':{   
            'star1': {'x': 0, 'y': 10},
            'star2': {'x': 0, 'y': 10}
        }
};
```

This object below in JavaScript can be  accessed as an hash table, faster!! I just want to do the some in Dart, but I am not sure if the best way is using Map.

```
const starsData = {
    stars:{
       'star1': {'x': 0, 'y': 10},
       'star2': {'x': 0, 'y': 10}
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your JavaScript implementation (based on the project your linked: https://github.com/ToniCalfim/fallingstars/blob/master/index.js) in Dart:

Can also be tested with:
https://dartpad.dev/900989f4e35e5a61200e4ad04ecd399a

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math' as math;

const starsDiameter = 1.25;

const colorPallete = [
  'white',
  'yellow',
  'blue',
  'red',
  'orange',
  'turquoise',
  'purple',
  'green',
  'lightblue',
  'lightyellow',
  'lightgreen',
  'darkred',
  'darkblue',
  'darkorange',
  'darkturquoise',
  'darkgreen'
];

final math.Random _rnd = math.Random();
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) => min + _rnd.nextInt(max - min);

class Star {
  int x, y;

  int positionX = getRandomNumber(2, 650);
  int positionY = getRandomNumber(3, 125);
  double diameter = starsDiameter;

  int pulsing = 0;
  int blinking = 0;

  int timeToFall = getRandomNumber(0, 7500);
  int velocityToFall = getRandomNumber(1, 5);
  int directionToFall = getRandomNumber(-1, 1);

  String color = colorPallete[getRandomNumber(0, colorPallete.length)];

  Star() {
    x = positionX;
    y = positionY;
  }
}

final List<Star> stars = List.generate(175, (_) => Star());

void update() {
  for (final currentStar in stars) {
    final currentTimeToFall = currentStar.timeToFall;

    if (currentTimeToFall != 0) {
      currentStar.timeToFall = currentTimeToFall - 1;
    } else {
      final currentVelocityToFall = currentStar.velocityToFall;
      final currentAngleToFall = currentStar.directionToFall;

      final currentPositionX = currentStar.x;
      final currentPositionY = currentStar.y;

      currentStar.x = currentPositionX + 1 * currentAngleToFall;
      currentStar.y = currentPositionY + currentVelocityToFall;
    }
  }
}

final CanvasElement canvas = querySelector('#canvas') as CanvasElement;
final CanvasRenderingContext2D context2D = canvas.context2D;

void drawStars() {
  context2D.clearRect(
      0, 0, context2D.canvas.width, context2D.canvas.height); // Clear canvas

  for (final currentStar in stars) {
    context2D.beginPath();
    context2D.fillStyle = currentStar.color;
    context2D.arc(currentStar.x, currentStar.y, starsDiameter, 0, 2 * math.pi);
    context2D.fill();
    context2D.closePath();
  }
}

void animateLoop([num highResTime]) {
  update();
  drawStars();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animateLoop);
}

void main() {
  animateLoop();
}
```

By looking at your code I could not see any reason why the stars should be saved in a Map or other Hash tables related structure. You are using the stars in two ways: draw and update. In both cases your are just going through all the stars which can be done by using a simple list and iterate over all elements.

I should add that I am not a front-end programmer and I cannot really judge if the way your are drawing the 2D canvas is the most efficient way to do that. My converted code are only are attempt to show how the data could be structured in  Dart.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope you can understand what I need. But I write down your exemple using  class.

Comment: I am really sorry but I have tried multiple times to get any meaning out of your question but I cannot find any clue about what you are trying to accomplish. You mention hash tables but do not say anything how you are going to access your objects. Please provide an example which shows what you want to do and describe why your own proposed solution does not work. E.g. do you want to access a star by its name or not?

Comment: I am so thank you!! Don't worry!! Check out my full code in JS using hash table:  https://github.com/ToniCalfim/fallingstars/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: julemand101, this was useful for me. Yesterday I wrote a version of FallingStars using Ameiva Lib, a project that I start just to learn to create a Dart lib and manager a project. If you want to collaborate  will be fine!!! This is my version of FallingStars:  https://github.com/ravencodde/ameiva/blob/master/example/main.dart